# Not able to find the sum of two choices in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code:

```
num1 = print(random.choice(range(1,7))) 
num2 = print(random.choice(range(1,7)))
```

I need to add num1 and num2:

```
total = num1 + num2
```

Gives an error

Comment: In your code, please place, just before the `total ...` line, a `print(num1)`, then execute the script and ask yourself, where is my beautiful number (musical score by Talking Heads)

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an error because you're assigning the result of `print` to a variable, and `print` returns `None`, not the value printed. (The error comes later, when you try to add these two `NoneType` values together.)

Change your code to assign the random values to your variables, then print those and add them together.

```
num1 = random.choice(range(1,7))
num2 = random.choice(range(1,7))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Return Value from print():
>
> It doesn't return any value; returns None.

```
import random
num1 = random.choice(range(1,7)) # num1 = None
num2 = random.choice(range(1,7)) # num2 = None

total = num1 + num2
print (total)
```